# Asp.net MVC4 WebDeploy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am deploying my MVC4 application to another server through `Web Deploy` and Everything works. However, when I include membership database to deployment, I do not see the local usernames and hashes in the remote database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebDeploy only deploys the database schema by default but you can add custom SQL scripts to the deployment.  Add the SQL script to create the usernames and add it to the scripts list under Project Settings | Package/Publish SQL | Database Scripts:

[image]